# Asserting that collection contains single matching item and then making further assertions on that item

Tags: kotlin, assertion

The test below employs the [strikt](https://strikt.io/) framework to first assert that the list contains a single pair satisfying `first=="B"` and then make an assertion on `second` of that pair.

```
@Test
fun `should verify that key occurs once and has expected value`() {
    val listOfPairs = listOf("A" to 1, "B" to 2, "C" to 3, "C" to 3)
    expectThat(listOfPairs).one { get { this.first }.isEqualTo("B") }
    expectThat(listOfPairs).filter { it.first.equals("B") }.single().get { this.second }.isEqualTo(2)
}
```

Is there a way to fluently continue the first `expectThat` to include the second assertion?
I'm aware that it is debatable whether this is actually desirable, but what I really don't fancy is that to access the pair again in the second `expectThat`, I need to use a predicate instead of an assertion.

Comment: Your second assertion's `single()` will fail if and only if the first assertion would fail. Therefore you can simply omit your first assertion entirely.

Comment: By the way, you can chain the assertions (just leave out the second "expectThat" and instead start the line with ".filter". Are you asking if you can assert not on `listOfPairs` but on the single element checked by `one()`?

Answer (score 0):

Given the return value of `one` doesn't expose any useful properties or methods, I think realistically you are looking at a [custom assertion](https://strikt.io/wiki/custom-assertions/).

This should fit the bill:

```
fun Assertion.Builder<List<Pair<String, Int>>>.hasKeyOnceWithValue(key: String, value: Int): Assertion.Builder<List<Pair<String, Int>>> {
    return assert("Has key $key once in the list with value $value") { actual ->
        actual.singleOrNull { pair -> pair.first == key }
            ?.let { singlePair ->
                if(singlePair.second == value)
                    pass()
                else
                    fail(actual = actual, description = "Key was present but had value ${singlePair.second}")
            }
            ?: fail(actual = actual, description = "Key was not present")
    }
}
```

And sample tests:

```
@Test
fun passes() {
    expectThat(listOf("a" to 1)).hasKeyOnceWithValue("a", 1)
}

@Test
fun failsAsDoesNotHaveKey() {
    expectThat(listOf("b" to 1)).hasKeyOnceWithValue("a", 1)
}

@Test
fun failsAsHasKeyButNotValue() {
    expectThat(listOf("a" to 2)).hasKeyOnceWithValue("a", 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather pointless to nest assertions; better chain them (as the documentation suggests):

```
expectThat(listOfPairs)
    .one { get { this.first }.isEqualTo("B") }
    .filter { it.first.equals("B") }.single().get { this.second }.isEqualTo(2)
```